# Jira configuration issue

Tags: xml, oracle, jira

I am trying to setup up the jira db connection credentials to use the oracle wallet for encryption.  Does anyone know how to do this?  I found this reference on it, although I could not get it working for me:

http://forum.liquibase.org/topic/using-oracle-wallet?reply=true

Thanks

Comment: Could you please add details on what is not working with your trials ? What have you tried, for instance ?

Comment: https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-805

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this format:

java -Doracle.net.tns_admin="path/to/directory/which/contains/tnsnames.ora" -cp "liquibase-version.jar" liquibase.commandline.Main --driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver --classpath="$Orahome/jdbc/lib/ojdbc5.jar:$Orahome/jlib/oraclepki.jar:$Orahome/jlib/osdt_core.jar:
 $Orahome/jlib/osdt_cert.jar" --url=jdbc:oracle:thin:/@connection_alias --logLevel=finest --logFile=liquibase.logFile --changeLogFile=changelog.xml --driverPropertiesFile="/path/to/file/with/required/database/connection/properties" update

I put this string in the place where the db password is stored in the file holding the database connection string.